# Connections between Biur Chametz and Tashlich?

Tags: commentaries, chametz-leaven, tashlich, biur-chametz

Are there any commentators that discuss the parallels between the rituals of *biur chametz* and *tashlich*?  At a surface level, both involve destroying or eliminating bread, one via fire and one via water (which are symbolically opposite to one another).  *Chametz* is broadly associated with the *yetzer hara*, and the bread that was cast into the water at *tashlich* symbolizes sins, so it seems clear that there are parallels.  Are there deeper connections?  Where are they discussed?

**ETA:**  To clarify, I understand that *halachically* there is no similarity between the two practices.  Symbolically, though, they seem similar ("destroying the chametz which represents our *yetzer hara*" vs. "casting away the bread to symbolize casting off our sins").  Something along those lines (but less superficial than what I have just written) is what I am wondering about.  Does anybody else talk about this?

Comment: I don't see it myself, especially since I've heard most people argue that we shouldn't throw bread into the water. But who knows? Maybe someone somewhere does talk about it. +1 for explaining the question thoroughly (imo).

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that nothing except they both have a kabolistic prayer after them

We can probably understand this better by seeing the prayer said after both procedures

Starts with May it be Your will.
[Chomets removal](http://m.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/1744/jewish/Search-Removal-and-Burning-of-Chametz.htm).
[Tashlich](http://m.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/427289/jewish/Tashlich-Prayer-English.htm)

What I see is that **chometz** removel (a biblical mitzva) is connected with the removel of evil power (Egypt) that ruled over us by the Passover time, and so we are also **destroying** and asking Hashem to destroy all evil
(I heard that chometz is also connected to gaava)

But **tashlich** is a minhag (see [What-is-Tashlich](http://m.chabad.org/holidays/jewishnewyear/template_cdo/aid/564247/jewish/What-is-Tashlich.htm)) to say pesukinm by a body of water (part of which are the Thirteen Divine Attributes of Mercy) seems not to be connected with destroing but to repentance and **forgiveness**

[Here](http://www.aish.com/h/hh/rh/guide/All_About_Tashlich.html) it even says that it is forbidden to through bread in the water

And even the part that says "cast all our sins into the depths of the sea," you can see from the original verse ([Micha 7.19](http://m.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16193#v=19)) that it is connected with compassion (not destruction)